# how to wrap the text inside the cell while using tabularx in latex?

Tags: latex

[image]

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|X|X|c|}

\hline
S.no & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{headline}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{article\_link}} & \bf\Centering is\_sarcastic \\ \hline
1 &
  man who said 'yes' to life found with mountain bike at bottom of gorge &
  {https://local.theonion.com/man-who-said-yes-to-life-found-with-mountain-bike-at-bo-1819573183} &
  1\\
\hline 
2 &
  tina fey is worried about what the internet is doing to society &
  {https://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/tina-fey-internet\_us\_5848252ce4b08c82e888ff80} &
  0 \\
\hline 
3 &
  why a woman refuses to leave her husband who threatened to kill her &
  {https://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/pro-fighter-allegedly-abuses-wife\_n\_6072618.html} &
  0 \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Don't write urls as text. There are packages like `url` or `hyperref` that provide a dedicated `\url{}` macro for them. This also saves you from manually escaping all special letters.
- to enable more possible breaking points to squeeze them into your way to narrow column, try the `xurl` package
- Never use two-letter font commands like `\bf`, they are deprecated
- Have a look at https://inf.ethz.ch/personal/markusp/teaching/guides/guide-tables.pdf for some suggestions about professional looking tables. Main point: don't use vertical lines

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xurl}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|X|X|c|}
\hline
S.no & \textbf{headline} & \textbf{article\_link} &  \textbf{is\_sarcastic} \\ \hline
1 &
  man who said 'yes' to life found with mountain bike at bottom of gorge &
  \url{https://local.theonion.com/man-who-said-yes-to-life-found-with-mountain-bike-at-bo-1819573183} &
  1\\
\hline 
2 &
  tina fey is worried about what the internet is doing to society &
  \url{https://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/tina-fey-internet_us_5848252ce4b08c82e888ff80} &
  0 \\
\hline 
3 &
  why a woman refuses to leave her husband who threatened to kill her &
  \url{https://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/pro-fighter-allegedly-abuses-wife_n_6072618.html} &
  0 \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]